# scss not recognizing $primary-color with use statement

Tags: import, sass

I have been having issues when converting to use from import using scss. I am getting an error saying that my variable of $primary color is not recognized. I am also getting an error simply saying "root stylesheet" I have tried several things including using the @import before the @use statement and adding a body selector into my style.scss which is my main file. I suspect it to be an issue with scss not finding the colors style sheet, but I am at a loss below find both the style.scss and the colors.scss
Help is appreciated

```
main.scss
    @use"../scss/colors";
    @use "../scss/globals";

body{
      color: $primary-color;
}

colors.scss
    $primary-color: maroon;
    $secondary-color: gold;
    $accent-color:green;
```